# Is there an easier way to set a DateTime in SQL Server to be 23:59:59

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Morning All,

I'm trying to refactor an SQL stored procedure. I'm no SQL expert, but something tells me there must be a better way to do this.

```
IF @ipv_dtEndDate IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ipv_dtEndDate = DATEADD(hh,23,@ipv_dtEndDate)
        SET @ipv_dtEndDate = DATEADD(mi,59,@ipv_dtEndDate)
        SET @ipv_dtEndDate = DATEADD(ss,59,@ipv_dtEndDate)
    END
```

This value is used later inside a `WHERE` clause. These filters seem difficult to understand to me. I was hoping to come up with a cleaner implementation.

```
AND qtrh.StatusTime <= IsNull(@ipv_dtEndDate, qtrh.StatusTime)
```

And this date calculation...

```
AND DATEDIFF(ss,qtrh.StatusTime,ISNULL(@dtNow,DATEADD(ss,-1,qtrh.StatusTime))) < DATEDIFF(ss,ISNULL(@dtDateOptionCompare,GETDATE()),GETDATE())
```

... seems quite convoluted and unreadable. If any SQL gurus out there have some suggestions on how I can improve this, I would love to hear some ideas. Thanks for your time. Have a terrific holiday weekend.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Its 9:40 PM here. Good night.

Comment: If @ipv_dtEndDate has a time, this is not only harder to read, but incorrect. If you're trying to set the time to 23:59:59, you have to clear it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only use of `@ipv_dtEndDate` is inside the Where clause, you could remove the entire `IF @ipv_dtEndDate IS NOT NULL` block, and replace the condition in the SQL query with:

```
AND qtrh.StatusTime < DATEADD(dd,1,IsNull(@ipv_dtEndDate, qtrh.StatusTime))
```

(Strictly speaking, you will now also be including StatusTime values between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00, which were previously excluded.)

Comment: +1 : endpoint exclusion logic is so much better than -1 endpoint logic.  It preserves the capability to compute durations (and that should be enough reason to use it).

Comment: does this add a day to StatusTime if @ipv_dtEndDate is Null?

Comment: @HCabnettek: yes - this ensures that the condition is always true if @ipv_dtEndDate is null, since `qtrh.StatusTime < DATEADD(dd,1,qtrh.StatusTime)` is always true (where qtrh.StatusTime is not null).

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
SET @ipv_dtEndDate = CONVERT(varchar, @ipv_dtEndDate, 101) + ' 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use < and the date for the next day rather than trying to run a <+ with the last second of midnight.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the date to varchar, add your "23:59:59" and then convert it back to datetime

Answer (score 0):

If you feel uncomfortable with the varchar approach, you can do the following.

```
SET @ipv_dtEndDate = DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, 0, '11:59:59'), @ipv_dtEndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a date without a time (rather, with the time set to "midnight the morning of") to the "end of the day",
you can just add the number of seconds:

```
DECLARE @ipv_dtEndDate datetime

SET @ipv_dtEndDate = 'Sep 3, 2010'
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @ipv_dtEndDate, 109)  --  Before

SET @ipv_dtEndDate = dateadd(ss, 1439, @ipv_dtEndDate)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @ipv_dtEndDate, 109)  --  After
```

Of course, SQL datetime is accurate to the [333rd of a] millisecond, so the end of the day is actually:

```
DECLARE @ipv_dtEndDate datetime

SET @ipv_dtEndDate = 'Sep 3, 2010'
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @ipv_dtEndDate, 109)  --  Before

SET @ipv_dtEndDate = dateadd(ms, 1439997, @ipv_dtEndDate)
PRINT convert(varchar(50), @ipv_dtEndDate, 109)  --  After
```

Using the built in (and mathematically based) date/time functions will be more efficient than converting to character strings and back.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the latest time for **today**:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, -2, DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Just substitute `GETDATE()` with whatever you want to be inclusive.  So, in your example:

```
AND qtrh.StatusTime <= DATEADD(ms, -2, DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @ipv_dtEndDate)))
```